# Cleveref: refer to labels of another version of the document

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a paper for a conference. Because of a line limit, not everything fits into the paper; instead, I am preparing a full version that will be uploaded to the arXiv that contains additional material as an appendix.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{placeins,etoolbox,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newif\iffullversion
\fullversiontrue
\fullversionfalse
\iffullversion
    \edef\jobname{\detokenize{fullversion}}
    \crefname{appendixfigure}{Figure}{Figures}
\else
    \usepackage{xr}
    \externaldocument{fullversion}
\fi

\usepackage{apptools}
\newcommand{\CExtra}[3]{
    \AtAppendix{\crefalias{#1}{appendix-#1}}
    \iffullversion
        \crefname{appendix-#1}{#2}{#3}
    \else
        \crefformat{appendix-#1}{#2 ##2##1##3 in the full version}
        \crefrangeformat{appendix-#1}{#3~##3##1##4 to~##5##2##6 in the full version}
        \crefmultiformat{appendix-#1}{#3~##2##1##3}{ and~##2##1##3 in the full version}{, ##2##1##3}{and~##2##1##3 in the full version}
    \fi
}
\CExtra{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\CExtra{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\CExtra{remark}{Remark}{Remarks}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    See \cref{fig:figure in appendix,fig:figure in appendix2}. % Should print as: Figure nn in the full version
    
    See \crefrange{fig:figure in appendix}{fig:figure in appendix2}.
    
    See \cref{thm:app,rmk:app}.
    
    See \cref{rmk:app}.
    \iffullversion
    \appendix   
    \FloatBarrier
    \section{An appendix}
    \begin{figure}
        \rule{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}
        \caption{A figure}
        \label{fig:figure in appendix}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \rule{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}
        \caption{A figure}
        \label{fig:figure in appendix2}
    \end{figure}
    See \cref{fig:figure in appendix} % Should print as: Figure nn
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{thm:app}
        Theorem.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{remark}
        \label{rmk:app}
        Theorem.
    \end{remark}
    \fi
\end{document}
```

- Is there a better approach to what I want?

Comment: Assuming online documents, package hyperref should work like \url{.../arXiv/whatever#tagged}. I assume this one put sth. like that in its LaTeX file: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.13746.pdf . It also combines my fallback solution, citation, with a link, see ref [16].

Comment: I think this is not trivial at all, because, if you just omit the part of the source with your `\ifarxivversion` the labels in that part won't be set, and thus won't be available in the `.aux` file. On the other hand, if you use something a little more sophisticated, like typesetting that part in a box and omit it in the conference paper, the labels will be set, but the counters will be stepped and, as a result the stripped down version will have "gaps" in the counters. But perhaps someone has some good idea, folks here never cease to surprise me.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, the gaps are a problem. Let's assume that all additional material is in an appendix.

Comment: @Bubaya One idea which might work is to consider the full version as an "external file" and use `xr-hyper` to make references from it. But, regardless, you've been around long enough and probably know this is the kind of question that stands a much better chance of getting a good answer if you provide a MWE with which people can "play with", without having to reinvent the wheel and guess the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @gusbrs True. I'll ask this again with a MWE.

Comment: @Bubaya Just editing your question with it will do fine.

Comment: @gusbrs Updated.

Comment: @Bubaya I see you have a working proof of concept. That's more or less what I had in mind in suggesting `xr`. But you are right, it is not really neat. Perhaps someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most promising approach to this problem would be to store the "in the full version" suffix with the label itself. Because, otherwise, you'll be into an uphill battle of redefining every needed `crefformat` or, alternatively, every `\the<counter>` out there. Unfortunately, we cannot hook after `\@currentlabel` with the new hook system because it gets redefined at every call of `\refstepcounter` and the hook is gone. So, short of redefining `\label` itself, and `cleveref`'s variants of it, you're in a tight spot.

The best I could think of was a `zref`/`zref-clever` solution, where I leverage `zref`'s extensibility and create a new property `defaultplus` where the suffix is included as appropriate, and then we can set `zref-clever` to use that property by default. The result is not terribly appealing for multiple labels of the same type in a given reference, but I think this is the most I can stretch the use case.

We also need `zref-xr`, as discussed in the comments, to be able to get the labels from the "fullversion" when building the restricted one. Which entails another caveat of this solution. Since we cannot use the prefix argument of `\zexternaldocument` when importing the labels from `fullversion` when running the restricted version -- because, well, they are meant to be the same labels in the same document -- the labels which belong to both versions of the document will try to appear in duplicity. That's why I'm running `\zexternaldocument` at `begindocument`, so that the current version's labels prevail. But I don't see a way to avoid the corresponding warnings "label XYZ is already in use in file `fullversion.aux'". But, besides being annoying,they should otherwise be harmless, you know why they are there.

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newif\iffullversion
\fullversiontrue
\fullversionfalse

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{defaultplus}{\my@currentlabelplus}
\zref@addprop{main}{defaultplus}
\newcommand{\my@currentlabelplus}{\@currentlabel}
\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{%
  \renewcommand{\my@currentlabelplus}{%
    \@currentlabel%
    \string\iffullversion\string\else
      \string\ in the full version%
    \string\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\zcsetup{
  cap,
  noabbrev,
  ref=defaultplus,
}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\iffullversion
  \edef\jobname{\detokenize{fullversion}}
\else
  \usepackage{zref-xr}
  \AddToHook{begindocument}{\zexternaldocument{fullversion}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}
  \rule{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}
  \caption{A figure}
  \zlabel{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

See \zcref{fig:figure in appendix}. % Should print
% as: Figure nn in the full version

See \zcref{fig:figure1}. % Should print as: Figure nn

\iffullversion
  \appendix
  \FloatBarrier
  \section{An appendix}
  \begin{figure}
    \rule{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}
    \caption{A figure}
    \zlabel{fig:figure in appendix}
  \end{figure}
  See \zcref{fig:figure in appendix} % Should print as: Figure nn
\fi

\end{document}
```

With `\fullversiontrue`:

[image]

With `\fullversionfalse`:

[image]

Comment: To resolve the issue with the duplicate entries, one could define a `\FullVersionPrefix` that depends on `\iffullversion`, use it as prefix for `\zexternaldocument` and reference using `\zcref{\FullVersion fig:figure in appendix}`

Comment: @Bubaya It would be a possibility, if you are willing to increase the complexity of the conditional markup. Up to you, of course, to do so in your actual document.